# Is there a quality difference between the unofficial iPhone replacement screens and the official?

Tags: iphone, screen

I want to replace my scratched up screen (GSM iPhone 4) and been looking into the options. I've seen that there are 100$ 'Official' replacements and the much more common eBay 30$ replacements. Is there a quality difference between the two or is this a case of which side of the factory these came out of? (ie. the Apple approved front door or out of the back door).

Answer (score 2):

I purchased one of the cheap replacements and it seemed identical during installation and right afterward, but it soon became apparent that the oleophobic (oil "fearing") coating  was either missing or very different. My screen is constantly filmy and gross and is extremely difficult to clean. It will come clean after a lot of buffing, but within an hour or two is back to being gruesome.

(I'm at the end of my contract and will soon replace it; otherwise I'd spring for the full-priced one and swap it out in an instant.)

Comment: Except for the coating (which I do not expect from a cheap knock off), how is the screen's quality? I've heard of yellowing and people seeing the capacitive matrix, is there truth to that?

Comment: @Ziv There may well be multiple manufacturers, so I can't say with certainty, but mine doesn't have either of those problems, and I've had it for over a year. No yellowing, and can't see the matrix.